# Debit credit query but with same dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing issue in getting balance from debit credit record. But in my table dates are same but debit credit is different.

[image]

```
declare @StartDate Datetime = '2018-11-03';
declare @EndDate Datetime = '2018-11-03';
Select 
        y.Description,
        y.DateTime, 
        y.Credit, 
        y.Debit,
        SUM(ISNULL(x.Debit, 0) - ISNULL(x.Credit, 0))  AS Balance
    FROM Accounts x 
    INNER JOIN Accounts y ON x.DateTime <= y.DateTime
    WHERE 
            CONVERT(date, y.DateTime) >= CONVERT(date, @StartDate) 
        AND 
            CONVERT(date, y.DateTime) <= CONVERT(date, @EndDate)

    GROUP BY
        y.DateTime, 
        y.Credit, 
        y.Debit,
        y.Description
    Order By
        y.DateTime
```

And my result is not what i want.

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I need every row balance. Debit credit and balance.

Comment: SELECT 
  t.DateTime, 
  t.Description, 
  t.Credit ,
  t.Debit ,
  SUM(t.Debit - t.Credit) OVER (ORDER BY t.DateTime, t.Credit, t.Debit, t.Id) AS Balance
 FROM Accounts t
  
 WHERE 
   CONVERT(date, t.DateTime) >= CONVERT(date, @StartDate) 
  AND 
   CONVERT(date, t.DateTime) <= CONVERT(date, @EndDate)
  
 ORDER BY t.DateTime

Comment: i also try this code but this is not getting old balance to calculate new balance.

Comment: What is the purpose of joining table accounts with itself?

Comment: It seems that table X has no role in your query

Comment: What or how do you know starting balance?

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by using window function

```
select 
   DateTime, 
   Credit, 
   Debit, 
   (select sum(Debit - Credit) from Account a where a.Datetime < t.DateTime) +
   Sum(Debit - Credit) Over (Order by DateTime) balance
from Account t
```

Comment: SELECT t.DateTime, t.Description, t.Credit , t.Debit , SUM(t.Debit - t.Credit) OVER (ORDER BY t.DateTime, t.Credit, t.Debit, t.Id) AS Balance FROM Accounts t WHERE CONVERT(date, t.DateTime) >= CONVERT(date, @StartDate) AND CONVERT(date, t.DateTime) <= CONVERT(date, @EndDate) ORDER BY t.DateTime

Comment: I already do this but this is not giving proper result. And also need old balance from that date.

Comment: DateTime          Credit  Debit    Balance
2018-11-03 09:46:36.233   0  100  100
2018-11-03 09:46:36.233   0  200  300
2018-11-03 09:46:36.233   0  200  500
2018-11-03 09:46:36.233   0  300  800

Comment: This is what i want.
Old Balance is 1000
DateTime    Credit  Debit  Balance
2018-11-03 09:46:36.233   0  100  1100
2018-11-03 09:46:36.233   0  200  1300
2018-11-03 09:46:36.233   0  200  1500
2018-11-03 09:46:36.233   300 0  1200

Comment: just get the old balance and sum with this? btw since the Balance is calculated column, how do you get old balance? it is not saved anywhere right?

Comment: Yes it is not save anywhere. I just have debit and credit column. So when i pass start and end date so i want transaction between that dates with old balance from that start date and that balance is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question and comments correctly this is what you are looking for:

```
declare @StartDate Datetime = '2017-11-03';
declare @EndDate Datetime = '2019-11-03';

Select DateTime, Credit, Debit
     , -- Get the prior Balance
       (select sum(ISNULL(Debit, 0) - ISNULL(Credit, 0))
          from Account p
         where CONVERT(date, p.DateTime) < CONVERT(date, @StartDate))
       -- and add it to the running total
     + sum(ISNULL(t.Debit, 0) - ISNULL(t.Credit, 0))
       over (order by DateTime, id) Balance
  from Account T
 where CONVERT(date, DateTime) >= CONVERT(date, @StartDate) 
   and CONVERT(date, DateTime) <= CONVERT(date, @EndDate)
 order by DateTime, ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
USE [YourDataBase]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Balance_Sheet]    Script Date: 5/16/2019 3:13:53 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Balance_Sheet]
 @StartDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
 
 
Select 
 
    x.DateTime, 
    x.Comments,
    x.Credit, 
    x.Debit, 
    SUM(coalesce(y.Credit, 0) - coalesce(y.Debit, 0))  AS Balance
FROM Balance x 
INNER JOIN Balance y
    ON y.DateTime <= x.DateTime
   where x.DateTime >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,@StartDate),0) and x.DateTime<dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,@EndDate)+1,0)
 
GROUP BY
    x.DateTime, 
    x.Credit, 
    x.Debit,
 x.Comments

END
```

Comment: Kashif i try that but it has some issue when we have same dates but time is change.